# ssrs format phone to (xxx)xxx-xxxx

Tags: reporting-services

I have problem formatting a phone number, for example, `(850)661-5665` for a report

Here is my sql script for phone number

```
CASE WHEN workPhoneAreaCode !='' 
THEN '('+ LEFT(workPhoneAreaCode,3) + ') ' 
      + SUBSTRING(workPhoneNumber, 4,3) 
      + '-'
       + RIGHT(workPhoneNumber,4) 
ELSE '' 
END PhoneNumber`
```

This work on the database display `(850)661-5665` as I wanted but on the report its does not work, it displays `850-661-5665`,

I also try on the ssrs expression

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!workPhoneAreaCode.Value),"(" +Fields!workPhoneAreaCode.Value+")"+ IsNothing(Fields!workPhoneNumber.Value),"")
```

which produces an error.

Comment: I have found the solution for this.

Comment: You should post your solution so other folks with the same question might some day benefit.